# visible background scroll when dialog is appear

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css

According to the [tutorial here](http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/) I used `bootstrap3` dialog. And works well. now want to make as visible background scroll and scroll should work when dialog is appear. How to do it?

```
$( ".target" ).click(function() {
    BootstrapDialog.show({                
        title: 'Default Title',
        message: $(this).attr("article")              
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
.modal-open {
    overflow: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `!important`